# Cannot create VSTS Security Group using API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to create new project-level security groups using the vsts api.

- Creating a new group at the [collection level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/graph/groups/create#create_a_group_at_the_account_level) works as documented.
- However, creating a new group at the [project level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/graph/groups/create#create_a_group_at_the_project_level) isn't working. When I call the API as documented, I end up with another a group at the collection level.

How should the create work at the project level? Is there someplace I should be looking for more examples and clarification?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below REST API to create a project level security group:

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_api/_identity/ManageGroup

Content-Type : application/json

{"name":"GroupNamehere","description":"Create a Test Group 0505 ","tfid":""}
```

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I needed! Thanks for the help!
Could I ask how you know about this endpoint and it is documented somewhere?

Comment: Oh, I see. You grabbed it out of your browser. :) Good show!