# Create Azure Devops (security) group like 'Contributors' with Permissions via Rest API or Client DLL

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have to create Azure Devops project level groups with specific permissions. Because there are several teams in a team project which should not affect each other, I want to create distinct groups and do not want to use i.e. 'Contributors'.
I managed to create a group and to retrieve this group (Identity). The default permissions are (or course) 'NOT SET'.

Fetching the list of security namespaces, I could use 'QueryAccessControlList' or 'HasPermissions' but I need a string-Token and a list of IdentityDescriptors to get the permissions of a group.

```
            var securityNamespaces = securityService.GetSecurityNamespaces();
            foreach (var secns in securityNamespaces)
            {
                secns.QueryAccessControlList(?? string-Token and IdentityDescriptors ?? );
            }
```

Where can I find these parameters?

The idea is to configure a group manually in the web portal, retrieve the set permissions and set them to my new groups.
Alternatively I could use tfssecurity.exe. But the /a+ option needs the parameters 'namespace token action identity' and I guess this is the same 'token' I am missing :-( 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a project level security group through the below rest api:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_api/_identity/ManageGroup
```

Request body:

```
{"name":"GroupNamehere","description":"Create a Test Group ","tfid":""}
```

Authentication uses PAT token.

[image]

Then you can use the below rest api to set permission,this api is grabbed from the browser by pressing `f12`.

```
Request URL: https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proId}/_api/_security/ManagePermissions?__v=5
```

Sample request body:

```
{"updatePackage": "{"IsRemovingIdentity":false,"TeamFoundationId":"be207790-f8ea-4ce0-9bcf-d8b4920c2af7","DescriptorIdentityType":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity","DescriptorIdentifier":"S-1-9-1551374245-3902060889-2001379654-2338155045-4044170422-1-3881783123-407997253-3219626845-873774695","PermissionSetId":"52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819","PermissionSetToken":"vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/59b994e8-4a77-46a1-8b5d-6a25f10d24b6","RefreshIdentities":false,"Updates":[{"PermissionId":1,"PermissionBit":1048576,"NamespaceId":"52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6baac873819","Token":"$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/59b994e8-4a77-46a1-8b5d-6a25f10d24b6:"}],"TokenDisplayName":null}"}
```

**Note** : `"Updates\":[{\"PermissionId\":1,` in the request body : 0 means `Not set`,1 means `Allow`, 2 means `Deny`

You can aslo refer to these: [Set version control permissions by REST API](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365828/set-version-control-permissions-by-rest-api.html), [case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394868/setup-team-or-users-permissions-with-vsts-rest-api) [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123574/cannot-create-vsts-security-group-using-api) . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I presume this works, but I was not completely satisfied. I will write an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hugh Lins answer is probably working, but I was not completely satisfied. Here are some useful hints (using the MS DLLs and .NET API).

```
IGroupSecurityService group_security_service;  // declared deprecated
group_security_service = team_project_collection.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
...
// create group
group_security_service.CreateApplicationGroup(prjinfo.Uri, sGroupName, sGroupDescription);
...
```

Extracting the permissions of a group (i.e. Contributores) we need:

- IdentityDescriptor of the group
- Security Token for every used security namespace

1.IdentityDescriptor

```
TeamFoundationIdentity tfs_id = identity_management_service.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.LocalGroupName,sGroup, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);
var desc = tfs_id.Descriptor
```

2.Token examples are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/security_tokens
We have to create a string which depends on the used security namespace.

```
var securityNamespaces = securityService.GetSecurityNamespaces();
```

For every security namespace the format of the token differs a litte bit.
For example for the 'Project' namespace:
`$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/xxxxxxxx-a1de-4bc8-b751-188eea17c3ba'`

The vstfs:///...-Uri comes from here:

```
prjinfo = common_structure_service4.GetProjectFromName(sTeamProject);
--> prjinfo.Uri
```

For calling QueryAccessControlList we need the descriptor as array parameter:

```
IdentityDescriptor[] tfidDescriptors = new IdentityDescriptor[] {desc};
```

Call to QueryAccessControlList:

```
foreach (var secNS in securityNamespaces) 
{
  string sToken = CreateToken(secNS.Description.NamespaceId);
  AccessControlList acl = secNS.QueryAccessControlList(sToken, tfidDescriptors, false);
  foreach (var ace in acl.AccessControlEntries)
  {
     ace.Allow   vs.   ace.Deny  contain bit coded permissions
  }
}
```

Later we can set the permissions to another group.
(We have to separate INHERIT and ALLOW/DENY).
Example:

```
...
secNS.RemovePermissions(sToken, desc, inherits);
...
secNS.SetPermissions(sToken, desc, allows, denies, true);
```

Cheers.